# Matching a union of strings and objects in typescript and preserving values

Tags: typescript, rust, enums

I'm using a crate (`typescript_type_def`) to auto-generate some Typescript types from Rust ones. Rust has the concept of enums with associated values, which Typescript does not. So the Rust crate, when encountering an enum, translates:

```rust
struct StructT {
  num: uint,
}
enum EnumWithValues {
  TupleVal(uint, uint),
  StructVal(StructT),
  SimpleVal,
}
```

into

```js
type StructT = { num: number };
type EnumWithValues = (
  { "TupleVal": [number, number] } |
  { "StructVal": StructT } |
  "SimpleVal"
);
```

I'd like to be able to write a function that receives anything produced by this transform, say `Enum<T>`, and will call a callback with the enum name and the associated values as arguments, e.g.:

```js
const myValue: EnumWithValues = /*...*/;

matchEnum(myValue, (val, args) => {
  // val would be of type "TupleVal" | "StructVal" | "SimpleVal"
  // args type would depend on val
});
```

I'm not sure how to approach this in typescript. A start, which does not produce accurate types, is:

```js
type EnumType = string | { [K: string]: unknown };
type RecordType<T extends EnumType> = T extends string ? never : T;
type EnumValue<T extends EnumType> = T extends string
  ? string
  : RecordType<T>[keyof T];

export const matchEnum = <T extends EnumType, RT>(
  enm: T,
  arm: (key: EnumValue<T>, v?: unknown) => RT
): RT => {
  if (typeof enm == "string") {
    return arm(enm as EnumValue<T>);
  } else {
    const k = Object.keys(enm)[0];
    return arm(k as EnumValue<T>, enm[k]);
  }
};
```

It seems possible that in the above example, `v` will never have a single type, rather the union of all possible record types - but in theory another type utility, say `EnumVal<T extends EnumType, K extends keyof T>` could potentially produce the right type.

Comment: Updated the rust types & generated types.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WK3jMW) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: wow @jcalz I believe that does! Much simpler than I expected too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach I'd take is to define a utility type `ArmArgs<T>` that produces a  [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) of [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) corresponding to the [parameter list](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types) the `arm` callback in `matchEnum()` accepts. So if `T` is `{a: A} | {b: B} | "c"`, then `ArmArgs<T>` should look like `[val: "a", args: A] | [val: "b", args: B] | [val: "c", args: undefined]` or something like that.  You can see how this keeps track of the correlation between the `val` argument and the `args` argument.  Here's one way to do it:

```
type ArmArgs<T> =
  T extends object ?
  { [K in keyof T]: [val: K, args: T[K]] }[keyof T] :
  [val: T, args: undefined]
```

You can verify that it behaves as advertised:

```
type Test = ArmArgs<{ a: A } | { b: B } | "c">
// type Test = [val: "a", args: A] | [val: "b", args: B] | [val: "c", args: undefined]
```

And now `matchEnum()` has the call signature

```
declare const matchEnum: <T extends string | object, RT>(
  enm: T,
  arm: (...a: ArmArgs<T>) => RT
) => RT
```

I'm not worrying about the *implementation* of `matchEnum` or its typings; for generic conditional types like that you'll probably need a healthy dose of [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).  Presumably you can handle that part yourself.

---

Okay, let's test it out with your `myValue` input:

```
const result = matchEnum(myValue, (val, args) => {
  if (val === "SimpleVal") {
    return 15
  } else if (val === "StructVal") {
    return args.num // StructT
  } else {
    return args[1] // [number, number]
  }
});
// const result: number
```

Looks good.  The compiler infers that `T` is `EnumWithValues` and that `RT` is `number`, so the call to `matchEnum()` behaves like

```
/* const matchEnum: (enm: EnumWithValues, arm: (...a: 
     [val: "TupleVal", args: [number, number]] | 
     [val: "StructVal", args: StructT] |
     [val: "SimpleVal", args: undefined]
  ) => number) => number */
```

And you can see that inside the callback, the compiler understands that when you check `val` it narrows the apparent type of `args` accordingly.  This works because TypeScript supports [control flow analysis on destructured discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-6.html#control-flow-analysis-for-destructured-discriminated-unions).  So `val` and `args` are seen as destructured elements of a `[val, args]` array of type `ArmArgs<EnumWithValues>`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTgW3gcwM4B4AqA+KBeAKCikyggA9gIA7AE1SgHsAjAKwgGNgoB+IqAN5QA2gGkoAS2pQA1hBCMAZiQC6ALhEA3AIYAbDaIA0UbXDQbMYlSqgBfYXIXLMNtf2E79JY6fNQArnQQilIQtCoEBLScuqbQHIzUqNwI2sAcABYAotT+CBpYZJQ09FDJcFLIUAA+TGycwMYASjgAFPw0+d78pl2tAHSD2hrwSGYYOACU+LgtBNN4s5iRUlRwitoc0DCCUAD6e8NQAIx2BKsQ65vQAEK7B8waAExnoJAkEMn4sIgoGEJHHa2Gq7R5QO7A2oAIg4UOwBAA9AioG9oJhPtw8Fo9BoodooT5xiMbLUPDioFDmASTETwSTsV4YdTfKgNIFoiFqGEIgRUVAAMrAOD+LikLFCXJdSXMS52ADcvPA0ByeQA6hJgBkAGp6fyfb7tYhCKGYfxgXQQHW6KEaYTSy7Ge1wGyQ-jGwXCrhWm0CoUi4CkV3EKH8iQIc2WvRQ+YK6IcWJweKJL4IEBWvUaFUIdWa9OfBUEBJJbiJ1D+XSYqCpdLZSWtVN54ytTyEtALXACfgSZTNvT4PBYkNhiPe6ad4jERPAfxwaTHACs-GBEF0qGg3agvd0-cHHv9o8E-EnEGns5paH6kqgSN9noDS7Iq+g44nU5n0hZwmONhvdryMrgR1-0uCJiFsAhbEmBUEQAKigIsUzSTIswKLMc21XVPiAhAAOwVpOkzSV0LzVBCT6QZ+iOI9iDJRlTRHKNW1ZEQnWwgDrBBaiGVxPcvUY89mN4gMSS42ieOHC1vSYtkgk5bl+HbKAnUUp0oBghFEWRBCS0+ctgA0J0gA)